# Dynamically add tab using json field

Tags: android, android-studio

Well,I have been trying to figure it out how to add dynamic tabs from json field from server and somehow I was able to show it.I manually defined two tabs which has their own .java files for that.Those dynamic tabs are showing right after those two tabs but I don't know how to add fragment to that dynamic tab.I am bit confused how to put this but just please try to go through.

Deeply Appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a **(TabLayout + ViewPager)** combo. Then with the help of JSON parsing add the number of tabs you require on calling the activity and then call the fragment content to be refreshed with onTabSelectedListener for best performance stability. It works like a charm.

Comment: could you email me ? or anything you could post here, been through a lot but din't get exact match or I might not exact search keyword

Comment: wow @Shadab K that's exactly what I'm trying to do, any guidance?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to dynamically manage tab, is by using **ViewPager and Adapter**. If you want to know, how that `ViewPager` with `adapter` should look like, you can create new `Tabbed Activity` in `Android Studio`.

Right-click on your main package -> New -> Activity -> TabbedActivity
[image]

`Android Studio` will create sample Activity with `ViewPager` and adapter. You can analyze that code and modify according to your own preferences.